# problem playing mp3's in Fancybox under iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, fancybox, mp3, phpbb

I want to be able to use FancyBox for mixed media types on my phpBB board.  Thanks to a suggestion from Janis, I'm now able to display pdfs as html using pdf.js.  This demo works with both Windows browsers, and iOS browsers:

http://59plymouth.net/59test/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3353&p=22872#p22872

...except for mp3's.  Because there isn't a Fancybox data-type for "audio", I used "video", and it works - for Windows.  iOS just sits there; you can't manually start the player either.  I think somewhere Janis suggested he would consider adding this data-type, but I don't know if it ever happened.  Here's the snippet of rendered phpBB code:

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery1" data-type="video" href="./download/file.php?id=16192" data-caption="this is an audio"> <video width="350" height="auto" controls=""><source src="./download/file.php?id=16192"></video></a>
```

Because the attachment stream is retrieved using "file.php" based on id, there isn't a way to explicitly declare the mime-type in the href.  Does anyone have any ideas about how I can address this issue?

Comment: Here's a more basic test, which does not rely on phpBB except for "file.php", which delivers the mp3 stream:  http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/fancybox.html
The icon on the left (or top) references the file with a .mp3 extension.  The icon on the right (or bottom) references file.php.  Both play under Windows with data-type="video"  - on iOS, only the href specifying the mp3 file with an extension plays.  Same data; just, delivered a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!  in phpBB, file.php calls functions_download.php, where the Content-Type is set in the header.  For both videos (mp4) and audios (mp3), I was assigning video/mp4.  Windows browsers accommodate this, but not iOS.  I now set the Content-Type to audio/mpeg (what Fiddler reported when iOS downloads a file with a .mp3 extension), and it works.